# python active_directive to set attributes

Tags: python, active-directory

How do we set attributes using python active_directive. I have used following to set the mail property for the user, but its not working,

```
    import active_directive

    User = active_directory.AD_object ("LocalAdmin").find_user("User1")        
    print User.sAMAccountName
    print User.displayName
    print User.mail
    User.setattr("mail","User1@testmail.com")
```

Here. I'm able to get the attributes(displayName, mail) of 'User1'. but not able set the mail attribute by using setattr()

Note : I have full permission to add, remove the user or group into the domain. I'm able to add and remove the group in the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set email id for the ADUser by using following line,

```
   User.set(mail = "User1@testmail.com")
```